# Install custom libraries using R script in google cloud storage

Tags: r

I am trying to run a Machine Learning model written in R on data proc cluster and for these purposes, I need to install some custom libraries. The problem is that everytime I create a DATAPROC cluster, I have to install these libraries and it takes around 30 minutes to do so. What I would like to do instead is install the library in google cloud storage, somewhere in a bucket - so that I can be reused in future.

Here is the command that I am trying to use

`install.packages("caret",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org", dependencies = TRUE, lib='gs://dummy_folder/r_packages/')`

But I am facing an error - `'lib = "gs://dummy_folder/r_packages/"' is not writable`

How do I go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try building your own VM as Cloud Dataproc supports using custom VMs: 
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-images